# Change Chat Oneboxing to recognize SVGs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Chat oneboxes certain images into proper `img` elements when you post a bare URL. However, it doesn't work for SVGs, like

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Disney-infinite-copyright.svg
```

But if you use the `!` operator at the start, it forces it into an image, which works:

```
!http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Disney-infinite-copyright.svg
```

Since SVG is a known standard extension and widely supported on modern browsers, could chat automatically recognize SVGs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fair point, and easy enough. Added to the next build. Of course (as with the other image types), this only looks at file extensions, and just assumes if the URL ends with `.svg` (or `.jpg` etc.) that it's an image.

Comment: I assume we can override the extension sniffing in the url with the bang (`'!'`) if need be?

Comment: @casperOne Sure, that has always worked (even with SVGs, assuming browser support) -- if you put an exclamation mark before the URL, chat will just believe you that it's an image.